# Differentiability of a function $g(x, y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

We consider the function:
$$ g(x,y)=\begin{cases} x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})+y^2 \sin(\frac{1}{y}) \quad x \neq 0, y \neq 0 \\
x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}) \quad y=0, x \neq 0\\
y^2\sin(\frac{1}{y}) \quad x=0, y \neq 0\\
0 \quad x=0, y=0\end{cases} $$
it is continuous in all $\mathbb{R}^2$. The partial derivative of $g(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ are continuous for all $x \neq 0, y \neq 0$. If I want to calculate the partial derivative with respect to $x$ on the point $(x_0,0)$ with $x_0 \neq 0$, I solve the follow limit:
$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \, \frac{(x_0+h)^2\sin(\frac{1}{x_0+h})-x_0^2\sin(\frac{1}{x_0})}{h}=2x_0\sin(\frac{1}{x_0})-\cos(\frac{1}{x_0})$$
If I want to calculate the partial derivative with respect to $y$ on the point $(x_0,0)$, with $x_0 \neq 0$, I solve the follow limit:
$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \, \frac{x_0^2\sin(\frac{1}{x_0})+h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h})-x_0^2\sin(\frac{1}{x_0})}{h}=0$$.
$$ \frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}=\begin{cases} 2x\, \sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x}) \quad  x \neq 0\\
0 \quad x=0 \end{cases}. $$
From this I deduce that the partial derivative of $g$ with respect to $x$ is not continuous on $(0,y_0)$. In a similar way we prove that the partial derivative of $g$ with respect to $y$ is not continuous on $(x_0,0)$. This prove that the function is not differentiable in all the points of both axis. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is correct up to the very end. Being continuously differentiable is sufficient — but not necessary — for the function to be differentiable. Go back to the actual definition of differentiability.

**EDIT**: Recall that $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ if there is a linear map $T$ with the property that
$$\lim_{(h,k)\to 0}\frac{f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b)-T(h,k)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0.$$
If it exists, $T$ must be the matrix of partial derivatives of $f$ at $(a,b)$. So ... what does this give you here at, say, $(0,0)$ and $(a,0)$?

**EDIT EDIT**: So here is the verification that the function $g$ is differentiable at $(a,0)$ for $a\ne 0$. We need to see that
$$\lim_{(h,k)\to 0} \tfrac{(a+h)^2\sin(\frac1{a+h}) + k^2\sin(\frac1k) - a^2\sin(\frac1a) - (2a\sin(\frac1a)-\cos(\frac1a))h}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} = 0.$$
As you correctly said, the $k$ term is no problem, since
$$\frac{k^2|\sin(\frac 1k)|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} \le |k|\cdot\frac{|k|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} \le |k| \to 0.$$
Now, let $f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac 1x)$. Since $f$ is differentiable at $a\ne 0$,
$$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)h}h \to 0,$$
and therefore
\begin{align*}
\left|\tfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)h}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\right| &= \left|\tfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)h}h\cdot \tfrac h{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\right| \\ &\le \left|\tfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)h}h\right| \to 0,
\end{align*}
as needed.

Comment: Thank you, for the differenziability is it convenient to use the definition? Or exists an easier way?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, any time you are working with a piecewise-defined function you will need to. Of course, if the function fails to be continuous at a point, of course it cannot be differentiable at that point.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.

Comment: Is it possible that the function is differentiable  only in $(0,0)$?

Comment: Well, it's certainly fine (because $C^1$) at $(a,b)$ when $a,b\ne 0$. Now what about $(a,0)$? What is the candidate for the derivative map there?

Comment: Yes I forgot to say the only point of the axis in which the function is differentiable is (0,0). Sorry, I don't understand the last question.

Comment: What's the definition of differentiability at, say, $[a,0)$?

Comment: I was confused by your answer.  It seems to me (and perhaps this is my misinterpretation) that the **primary** question of the query is is $g(x,y)$ continuous on all $\mathbb{R^2}.$  Assuming so, why is it proper to assume that differentiability needs to be considered at all?  For example, in general, you can have a function $f(x,y)$ that potentially can approach $(0,0)$ from a variety of angles.  That doesn't necessarily mean that the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ *from any angle* can't still be = (0,0).

Comment: Maybe $\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{(a+h)^2sin(\frac{1}{a+h})+k^2sin(\frac{1}{h})-a^2sin(\frac{1}{a})h}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$?

Comment: @user2661923: The OP asserted continuity. Reread it carefully. :) The issue is differentiability at various points.

Comment: The continuty of the function is an affermation, isn't correct?

Comment: @Rick88 : My bad - I misread the query.  Thanks.

Comment: @Rick88: There has to be a linear map $T$ with the appropriate limit property. If it exists, it is the linear map given by the partial derivatives. So you have not properly understood that definition or written down what it requires here.

Comment: How can we prove the existance? If I prove that the limit is zero ?

Comment: See my edit. If it exists, it must be the matrix of partials. Now you have to check whether the limit is appropriately $0$. This should all be in your course :)

Comment: Yes, of course, it remain to prove that my limit is zero.

Comment: No, your limit is incorrect. Write out $f(a+h,k)-f(a,0)-T(h,k)$ carefully. You also have a typo in the $k$ term.

Comment: Yes but $g_y(a,0)=0$. When $a \neq 0$ I calculate that the limit does not exists. So I coclude that the function is differentiable in all points $(a,b)$ where $a \neq 0, b \neq 0$ and in $(0,0).$

Comment: You are incorrect, I believe. Please pay attention to details and write it put carefully.

Answer (score -1):

$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(a,0) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(a,h)-g(a,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{a^2\, sin(\frac{1}{a})+h^2\, sin(\frac{1}{h})-a^2\, sin(\frac{1}{a})}{h}=0$.\
If $g$ is differentiable in $(a,0)$, with $a \neq 0$, it holds:
$$ \lim_{(h,k) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{g(h,k)-g(a,0)-g_x(a,0)h-g_y(a,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} =0$$
The limit is:
$$\lim_{(h,k) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{h^2\, sin(\frac{1}{h})+k^2\, sin(\frac{1}{k})-a^2\, sin(\frac{1}{a})-[ 2a\, sin(\frac{1}{a})-cos(\frac{1}{a})]h-0 \cdot k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=$$
$$=\lim_{(h,k) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{h^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\, sin(\frac{1}{h})+\frac{k^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\, sin(\frac{1}{k})-\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\, sin(\frac{1}{a})-[ 2a\, sin(\frac{1}{a})-cos(\frac{1}{a})]\frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$
Both $\frac{h^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$ and $\frac{k^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} \rightarrow 0$, but $\lim_{(h,k) \rightarrow (0,0)}-\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\, sin(\frac{1}{a})-[ 2a\, sin(\frac{1}{a})-cos(\frac{1}{a})]\frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} = \mp \infty$. The limit is not zero, so the function is not differentiable in $(a,0)$.

Comment: Sloppy error. You need $g(a+h,k)$. The limit will in fact be $0$.

Comment: Even if I correct my limit, by inserting correctly $g(a+h, k) $, why is it zero?   Can you show me it?

Comment: See edit. It just boils down to the one-variable situation, and we know that the function $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ is differentiable (in fact, continuously differentiable) at $a\ne 0$.

Comment: It is clear, thank you very much!!